# Selecting last n columns and excluding last n columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, object-slicing

How do I:

1. Select last 3 columns in a dataframe and create a new dataframe?

I tried:

```
y = dataframe.iloc[:,-3:]
```

2. Exclude last 3 columns and create a new dataframe?

I tried:

```
X = dataframe.iloc[:,:-3]
```

Is this correct?

I am getting array dimensional errors further in my code and want to make sure this step is correct.

Thank you

Answer (score 59):

**The most efficient way:**

**1. Select last n columns**

`df1 = df.iloc[:,-n:]`

**2. Exclude last n columns**

`df1 = df.iloc[:,:-n]`

Answer (score 33):

just do:

```
y = dataframe[dataframe.columns[-3:]]
```

This slices the columns so you can sub-select from the df

Example:

```
In [221]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=np.arange(10))
df[df.columns[-3:]]

Out[221]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [7, 8, 9]
Index: []
```

I think the issue here is that because you have taken a slice of the df, it's returned a view but depending on what the rest of your code is doing it's raising a warning. You can make an explicit copy by calling `.copy()` to remove the warnings.

So if we take a copy then assignment only affects the copy and not the original df:

```
In [15]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,10), columns= np.arange(10))
df

Out[15]:
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0  0.568284 -1.488447  0.970365 -1.406463 -0.413750 -0.934892 -1.421308   
1  1.186414 -0.417366 -1.007509 -1.620530 -1.322004  0.294540  1.205115   
2 -1.073894 -0.214972  1.516563 -0.705571  0.068666  1.690654 -0.252485   
3  0.923524 -0.856752  0.226294 -0.660085  1.259145  0.400596  0.559028   
4  0.259807  0.135300  1.130347 -0.317305 -1.031875  0.232262  0.709244   

          7         8         9  
0  1.741925 -0.475619 -0.525770  
1  2.137546  0.215665  1.908362  
2  1.180281 -0.144652  0.870887  
3 -0.609804 -0.833186 -1.033656  
4  0.480943  1.971933  1.928037  

In [16]:    
y = df[df.columns[-3:]].copy()
y

Out[16]:
          7         8         9
0  1.741925 -0.475619 -0.525770
1  2.137546  0.215665  1.908362
2  1.180281 -0.144652  0.870887
3 -0.609804 -0.833186 -1.033656
4  0.480943  1.971933  1.928037

In [17]:    
y[y>0] = 0
print(y)
df

          7         8         9
0  0.000000 -0.475619 -0.525770
1  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2  0.000000 -0.144652  0.000000
3 -0.609804 -0.833186 -1.033656
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
Out[17]:
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0  0.568284 -1.488447  0.970365 -1.406463 -0.413750 -0.934892 -1.421308   
1  1.186414 -0.417366 -1.007509 -1.620530 -1.322004  0.294540  1.205115   
2 -1.073894 -0.214972  1.516563 -0.705571  0.068666  1.690654 -0.252485   
3  0.923524 -0.856752  0.226294 -0.660085  1.259145  0.400596  0.559028   
4  0.259807  0.135300  1.130347 -0.317305 -1.031875  0.232262  0.709244   

          7         8         9  
0  1.741925 -0.475619 -0.525770  
1  2.137546  0.215665  1.908362  
2  1.180281 -0.144652  0.870887  
3 -0.609804 -0.833186 -1.033656  
4  0.480943  1.971933  1.928037
```

Here no warning is raised and the original df is untouched.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of using integer indices (ix selects those by label over -3 rather than position, and this is by design: see integer indexing in pandas "gotchas"*).

*In newer versions of pandas prefer loc or iloc to remove the ambiguity of ix as position or label:

df.iloc[-3:]
see the docs.

As Wes points out, in this specific case you should just use tail!

It should also be noted that in Pandas pre-0.14 iloc will raise an IndexError on an out-of-bounds access, while .head() and .tail() will not:

> > > pd.**version**
> > >       '0.12.0'
> > >       df = pd.DataFrame([{"a": 1}, {"a": 2}])
> > >       df.iloc[-5:]
> > >       ...
> > >       IndexError: out-of-bounds on slice (end)
> > >       df.tail(5)
> > >          a
> > >       0  1
> > >       1  2
> > >       Old answer (depreciated method):

You can use the irows DataFrame method to overcome this ambiguity:

In [11]: df1.irow(slice(-3, None))
Out[11]: 
    STK_ID  RPT_Date  TClose   sales  discount
8      568  20080331   38.75  12.668       NaN
9      568  20080630   30.09  21.102       NaN
10     568  20080930   26.00  30.769       NaN
Note: Series has a similar iget method.