# Dropping multiple Pandas columns by Index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I have a large pandas dataframe (>100 columns). I need to drop various sets of columns and i'm hoping there is a way of using the old

```
df.drop(df.columns['slices'],axis=1)
```

I've built selections such as:

```
a = df.columns[3:23]
b = df.colums[-6:]
```

as `a` and `b` represent column sets I want to drop.

The following

```
list(df)[3:23]+list(df)[-6:]
```

yields the correct selection, but i can't implement it with a `drop`:

```
df.drop(df.columns[list(df)[3:23]+list(df)[-6:]],axis=1)
```

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,)
>   (6,)

I looked around but can't get my answer.

[Selecting last n columns and excluding last n columns in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042633/selecting-last-n-columns-and-excluding-last-n-columns-in-dataframe)

(Below pertains to the error I receive):

[python numpy ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560298/python-numpy-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shapes)

This one feels like they're having a similar issue, but the 'slices' aren't separate:
[Deleting multiple columns based on column names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538536/deleting-multiple-columns-based-on-column-names-in-pandas)

Cheers

Comment: Try `df.drop(columns=list(df)[3:23]+list(df)[-6:])`

Comment: That works too - as usual more than one way to skin a cat. This is more in line with what i was trying to get to, so thanks very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to seamlessly combine multiple ranges / slices:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(ascii_uppercase))

idx = np.r_[3:10, -5:0]

print(idx)

array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1])
```

You can then use `idx` to index your columns and feed to [`pd.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df.drop(df.columns[idx], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df.columns)

Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
       'O','P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I thought there would be some np function for slice combinations but I couldn't find it. Cheers

Comment: I got caught out on the need to define the end of the list slice (the 0 in `[-n:0]`) but think i understand now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

This returns the dataframe with the columns removed

```
df.drop(list(df)[2:5], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this simple solution:

```
cols = [3,7,10,12,14,16,18,20,22]
df.drop(df.columns[cols],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

the result :

```
    0   1   2   4   5   6   8   9    11  13      15     17      19       21
0   3   12  10  3   2   1   7   512  64  1024.0  -1.0   -1.0    -1.0    -1.0
1   5   12  10  3   2   1   7   16   2   32.0    32.0   1024.0  -1.0    -1.0
2   5   12  10  3   2   1   7   512  2   32.0    32.0   32.0    -1.0    -1.0
3   5   12  10  3   2   1   7   16   1   32.0    64.0   1024.0  -1.0    -1.0
```

As you can see the columns with given index have been all deleted.

You can replace the int value by the name of the column you have in your array if we suppose you have A,B,C ...etc you can replace int values in `cols` like this for example :

```
cols = ['A','B','C','F']
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
a = df.columns[3:23].values.tolist()
b = df.colums[-6:].values.tolist()

a.extend(b)
df.drop(a,1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar issue before and had trouble with this but fixed it by "subtracting" one df from the other, not sure if this will work for you but it did for me:

```
df = df[~df.index.isin(a.index)]
df = df[~df.index.isin(b.index)]
```